# How to pip install old version of library(tensorflow)?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow r0.11. I tried

```
pip install tensorflow==r0.11
pip install tensorflow<0.12
```

But I get this error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==0.11.0 (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==0.11.0
```

I assume pip is no longer support depricated versions, how can I get it?

I also tried

```
pip install git+git://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow@r0.11

Cloning git://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow (to r0.11) to /private/var/folders/1p/7km73m0s2cvdfb1js3ct8_mh0000gn/T/pip-JMMIRP-build
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/1p/7km73m0s2cvdfb1js3ct8_mh0000gn/T/pip-JMMIRP-build/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1p/7km73m0s2cvdfb1js3ct8_mh0000gn/T/pip-JMMIRP-build/
```

Comment: They've got binaries for the older versions on github along with several installation options described.

Comment: You can see the available versions in the output: `(from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1)`

Comment: @EliKorvigo can't find it, thx, doesn't seem to work, I went to the branch r.011 and tried to follow the link, it's broken https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-matrix-mac-gpu/TF_BUILD_IS_OPT=OPT,TF_BUILD_IS_PIP=PIP,TF_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON3,label=gpu-mac/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can install the pip wheel from a URL directly, for example:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

In general, installation instructions for older versions of TensorFlow can be found at :
For binaries for installation using wheels:
Go to [tensorflow pypi release history](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history), select the **release of your choice**, say `tensorflow 1.8.0` , go to **[Download files](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.8.0/)** and either download the wheel file and then install or copy the download link and save in `TF_BINARY_URL` for your `python --version` and **os** **[mac, linux or windows]** install as shown above

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7552#issuecomment-280239101) might also be of help, in case an error such as this arises : **tensorflow-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

Answer (score 22):

This works for me on Mac OS 10.13.1.

```
pip install --user install tensorflow==1.3.0.
```

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are useful, but the question remains: **why** doesn't pip have the older version? Because older TensorFlow versions were not built for the Python version you are running<sup>1</sup>. So pip can't find them.

If you want pip to find them, use a python version which TensorFlow was built for. For example, TensorFlow 1.14.0 was built for Python3.7, as can be seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.14.0/#files).

---

<sup>1</sup> This means both:

- no "source distributions" were published and
- no "built distributions"/`bdist_wheel`s were published for the combination of architecture, python version, and operating system.

For simple packages, source distribution can be used to compile dependencies during `pip install`, but tensorflow (or pytorch) don't provide source distributions, probably because it would unlikely work-for or suit most users, because:

- they require a lot of build dependencies on your machine, and
- the build is configurable.

Comment: Additionally, I noticed that updating (`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`) to the latest `pip` will get you the newer TensorFlow versions which may otherwise be missing through pip.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to install tensorflow **r0.11**, it means that you want to install the sources from a certain **branch** (**r0.11**). Therefore, you should follow the official installation instructions from tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources:

In case you want to install a "normal" release. then you can easily use the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.3.0.
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

`pip3 install 'tensorflow==1.2.0' --force-reinstall`

Comment: pip install 'tensorflow==1.2.0' --force-reinstall worked for me to reinstall in the virtual environment of Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own library/packet on github/gitlab etc, you have to add tag to commit with concrete version of library e.g. v2.0 then you can install your packet

```
pip install git+ssh://link/name/repo.git@v2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still relevant.
This is not a bug. Trying to install a non-compatible package will result in that error.
If you want to install an older version of Tensorflow, it has to be compatible with your python version.

Here are some useful links to ensure proper installation:
[Tensorflow installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native)
At the bottom of that link you'll find which python versions support GPU

For CUDA and CuDNN compatibility click [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)