# pip install <package>==version failed in installing tensorflow-gpu in mac which is shown in pip search

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I know there are lots of similar questions but I can not get answer from them.

It's very weird when I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0 just these days.
I can get tensorflow-gpu (1.7.0) from `pip search tensorflow-gpu`, but can't install it by `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0` due to versions don't contain 1.7.0.

pip version is 9.0.3

python version is 3.6.4

Any idea?

---

UPDATED:

Tensorflow no more support for mac after 1.1.0

[image]

Comment: I believe this is because no source distribution is available and no wheel is available either for macOS.  Looking at the tensorflow repo, it looks like CPU-only is supported for macOS right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pip install old version of library(tensorflow)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937915/how-to-pip-install-old-version-of-librarytensorflow)

Comment: @Abhishakegupta It's not a duplicate. I am trying to install latest version.

Comment: @jszakmeister You are right. Seems that is the reason.

Comment: It works only on 64 bit install of python. And your system architecture graphics card should support GPU version, usually Nvidia gpus are supported . If you can't then stick to CPU version..and why version==1.70.0 ? Let it pick by default based on requirements and latest pip version.

Comment: @Prateek b/c I used pip install without version and 1.1.0 installed. And I know latest version is 1.7.0 so I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Please see documentation for [Mac](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) that says

> Note: As of version 1.2, TensorFlow no longer provides GPU support on
>   macOS.

That means **you are not supposed to install** the GPU version if you intend to use version `1.2` and higher. Simply because its not officially supported.

In your case you are supposed to stick with version < 1.2.

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-in-pip?answertab=votes#tab-top) the question with many accepted answers on Stackoverflow per official site

Comment: @fumi_fwh please accept the answer if it addressed your issue.