# installing old tensorflow package from github

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, pip

i need a version 1 of tensorflow. its not available on pip.

but when i try

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15#egg=tensorflow
```

i get this error

```
Obtaining tensorflow from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15#egg=tensorflow
  Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15 to c:\users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow'
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15/' not found
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried many variations of urls to try and get tf 1.15 like below

```
git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15/site/en/api_docs/python/tf

git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.15/site/en/api_docs/python

etc...
```

they all give the same error

###################

update

i have tried

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
```

but basically get the same error

```
C:\Users\tgmjack>pip install -e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
Obtaining tensorflow from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
  WARNING: git clone in c:\users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow exists with URL https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
  WARNING: The plan is to install the git repository https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow
What to do?  (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup w
  WARNING: Deleting c:\users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow
  Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow (to revision r1.15) to c:\users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow'
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow/' not found
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

########## update 2

exact copy n paste of sugestion below. (weirdly i get another error suggesting versions are available)

```
C:\Users\tgmjack>pip install -e git+https://github.com/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
Obtaining tensorflow from git+https://github.com/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
  Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow (to revision r1.15) to c:\users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow'
  remote: Not Found
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/tensorflow/' not found
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

update 4

still....

```
C:\Users\tgmjack>pip install -e git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
Obtaining tensorflow from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow
  Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow (to revision r1.15) to c:\users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow 'C:\Users\tgmjack\src\tensorflow'
  Running command git checkout -b r1.15 --track origin/r1.15
  branch 'r1.15' set up to track 'origin/r1.15'.
  Switched to a new branch 'r1.15'
  Resolved https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow to commit 3db52be7be81a87c623cdeb7f03d3767521c5246
ERROR: tensorflow from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow@r1.15#egg=tensorflow does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937915/how-to-pip-install-old-version-of-librarytensorflow

Comment: im a few steps ahead of that. pip install tensorflow==1.15 isnt gunna work, its been removed. i need it from github.